# How to create Application specific directory on SDCard that should be deleted when the app is uninstalled

Tags: android

I want to use the device's SD Card for storing my application files, images, cache files etc on the device and use them in my application. I know that I can save them on the internal memory by using Context.getFilesDir() / Context.openFileOutput methods but I do not want my application to use internal memory for saving this data.

So is there any way I can create/save all my application specific files in a directory on the SD Card, but still be able to let the system know that these files have to be deleted when the application is uninstalled?

Or what are the recommendations in this case.

EDIT: I want to support 2.1 also.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok Thank you for the replies. It seems there is no easy way for this if I have to support pre 2.2 devices. So I am planning on adding images etc to the gallery on device and try to store everything else on the internal memory for now. But if it exceeds a threshold size I may redo this to store them also on sd card but rely on not being able to delete them for pre 2.2 devices. Please let me know if anyone has any alternate suggestions that might work better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your application doesn't get notified when it is being deleted, so you might be better off using the application's private directory, (from getFilesDir()). That directory is automatically deleted when the app is uninstalled.

Keep in mind that if you are on SDK 2.2+, you can allow your users the option of moving the entire application to the SD card, so you won't have to worry about the size of this directory.

Comment: Thank you, I want my application to run on 2.1 devices also. Any suggestions on how to do do this?

Comment: There is a great page on how to do this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

If you look under "Backwards Compatibility" it shows that there is a way to allow only the "move to sd card" functionality of the 2.2 SDK.

Answer (score 5):

Any files that are private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the system will take care of deleting if the application is uninstalled.
[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) might help.

Comment: Thank you, But I want to support 2.1 also. So this will not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a hack but it works for me...

```
File myFilesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/<package name>/files");
myFilesDir.mkdirs();
```

Replace `'<package name>'` with your package name.

**EDIT:** Thinking about it, it's possible it may only be 'cleaned up' on app un-installation on versions of Android from v2.2 onwards.

Comment: Thank you, I want my application to run on 2.1 devices also. Any suggestions on how to do do this?

Comment: @achie: No, I think the limitation is down to the fact that it works on v2.2+ because of the ability to install/move apps to external storage. Unfortunately, as has been mentioned, the un-installation process doesn't allow an app to know it's being un-installed. You could simply check for version number and store files to internal memory for pre-2.2 or do you think this would be a problem (size of files being stored etc)?

Comment: Yup, my app will also need a gallery and a cache of thumbnails and many more files. But Thank you for the replies. I guess I will have to not worry about deleting all the galleries myself and let user do that from gallery app. For the rest I may have to use sd card.